# Can we specify --from-file option when creating a configmap using yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am creating a config map as below

```
kubectl create configmap testconfigmap --from-file=testkey=testfile.txt
```

As I am using helm charts, I would like to create the config map using YAML file instead of running kubectl, so something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testconfigmap
data:
fromfile: testkey=testfile.txt
```

The `--from-file` allows me to pass the key and the value I read from the testfile.txt. But the `fromfile` doesn't work if I create configMap as YAML file.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Sanjay!!! To make it easier for others to help you consider providing a practical example of what you have tried, the output and short explanation of what you are trying to achieve. Also formatting your post makes is much easier for the people reading it, consider adding code blocks.

Answer (score -2):

The following command will generate the Yaml file you need to apply

```
kubectl create configmap testconfigmap —from-file=testkey=test file.txt —dry-run=client -o yaml > myconfigmap.yaml
```

Then you can just do

```
kubectl apply -f myconfigmap.yaml
```

Comment: This pair of commands can't be run in Helm.  If you have a Helm chart typically it will be self-contained and checked into source control, and you wouldn't use imperative `kubectl create` commands.